# How to get the two-digit number which is 3/8 of the number I get by swapping the digits of the original?

Tags: real-numbers

I know that 27 satisfies that requirement in the title:

$$72\cdot\frac{3}{8}=27$$

However, I've obtained this solution by a short python script checking all 2-digit numbers. How can I do better and find it fast by hand?

---

For those interested in the script itself:

```
import numpy as np
two_digit_numbers=np.arange(10,100)

def swap(number):
    number_string = repr(number)
    new_number_string = number_string[1]+number_string[0]
    new_number = int(new_number_string)
    return new_number

for number in two_digit_numbers:
    if number*8/3 == swap(number):
        print(number)
```

Comment: Well, the bigger number must be divisible by $8$, and the smaller by $3$, hence the larger must be divisible by $24$.

Comment: Oh ok that's good, thx.

Comment: Your short Python script used two variables to contain the two digits.  How did you combine those to get a number?  Is there a reason you can't do the same thing algebraically?

Comment: I should have been clearer:  the fact that the smaller one is divisible by $3$ means the larger one is also, hence the larger is divisible by $24$.  So you really just have to check $4$ numbers.

Comment: Added the script @Eric

Comment: Thank you @lulu, would you like to add that as an answer? I find it great

Comment: Convincing someone your code handles the digits correctly is harder than *actually having the digits* in variables.  See the two answers for how you should be thinking about digital problems.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I know it's not super ideal... Just wanted to get a quick initial answer, that's why I did it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative method, note that the larger number must be divisible by $8$ and the smaller by $3$.

Now, as an integer is divisible by $3$ if and only if the sum of its digits is, it follows that the larger number is also divisible by $3$, hence by $24$.

Thus the larger number must be one of $\{24, 48, 72, 96\}$ and it is easy to test each case.

Comment: Notice that as a little refinement, since the smaller number is less than $37<99\times \frac 38$, only $24$  and $27$ need to be tested.

Answer (score 4):

$$8(10a+b)=3(10b+a)$$ or

$$77a=22b$$

or

$$7a=2b.$$

Answer (score 2):

Write your number in digits as $10a + b$ where $a,b \in \{ 1, 2 , \dots , 9\}$. Then you're solving
\begin{align}
10a + b = \frac{3}{8} (a + 10 b) \Leftrightarrow 80a + 8b = 3a + 33b \Leftrightarrow 77a = 22b \Leftrightarrow 7a = 2b,
\end{align}
and you can just read off $a=2$ and $b=7$ from there.